# Error when calling the login route of my Symfony 6 API on Flutter

Tags: php, flutter, symfony, http

I have a Flutter mobile application with a login page so that my user can connect, and I want to link this to my Symfony back-end (API) with a mySQL database.
The problem is that when I try to call the login route on my flutter front-end it doesn't work, but when I try to call my route on Postman it works fine.

**Fristly, my LoginController Symfony :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/login', name: 'login', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function login(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordHasher): Response
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $mail = $data['mail'];
        $password = $data['password'];

        $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['mail' => $mail]);

        if (!$user) {
            return $this->json(['etat' => false, 'message' => 'Email invalide'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if (!$passwordHasher->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
            return $this->json(['etat' => false, 'message' => 'Mot de passe invalide'], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return $this->json(['etat' => true, 'message' => 'Connexion reussie'], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }

}
```

What I get when I test on Postman with an email and password that are in my database :
**In Postman : **
Method POST, url : http://127.0.0.1:8000/login

```
body :
{
"mail": "g.mail@mail.fr",
"password": "myPassword"
}
response :
{
"etat": true,
"message": "Connexion reussie"
}
```

If I enter an email address and/or a password that are not in my database (in my user table) :
Two possible responses :

```
{
"etat": false,
"message": "Email invalide"
}
```

Or

```
{
"etat": false,
"message": "Mot de passe invalide"
}
```

If neither the email address nor the password is in my table, I'll get this answer:

```
{
"etat": false,
"message": "Email invalide"
}
```

For information, in Postman when the connection is successful it gives me a 200 and when the email doesn't exist a 400 "Bad Request" and when it's the password that doesn't exist a 401 "Unauthorized" and when it's both a 400.

**Now my Flutter code login_page.dart :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:room_manager/pages/sign_in_page.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State\<LoginPage\> createState() =\> \_LoginPageState();
}

class \_LoginPageState extends State\<LoginPage\> {

final \_formKey = GlobalKey\<FormState\>();

final mailController = TextEditingController();
final passwordController = TextEditingController();

@override
void dispose() {
super.dispose();
mailController.dispose();
passwordController.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("Connexion"),
),
body: Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
child: Column(
children: \[
const Text(
"Connectez-vous",
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 28,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
),
),
SizedBox(height: 30),
Form(
key: \_formKey,
child: Column(
children: \[
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
child: TextFormField(
decoration: const InputDecoration(
labelText: 'E-mail',
hintText: "Entrez votre e-mail",
border: OutlineInputBorder(),
),
validator: (value) {
if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
return "Renseignez votre e-mail";
}
return null;
},
controller: mailController,
),
),
Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
child: TextFormField(
decoration: const InputDecoration(
labelText: 'Mot de passe',
hintText: "Entrez votre mot de passe",
border: OutlineInputBorder(),
),
obscureText: true,
validator: (value) {
if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
return "Renseignez votre mot de passe";
}
return null;
},
controller: passwordController,
),
),
SizedBox(
width: double.infinity,
height: 50,
child: ElevatedButton(
onPressed: () async {
if (\_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
final mail = mailController.text;
final password = passwordController.text;

                          final url = Uri.parse('http://192.112.148.1:8000/login');
                          final response = await http.post(
                            url,
                            body: {
                              'mail': mail,
                              'password': password,
                            },
                          );
                          print('Response status code: ${response.statusCode}');
                          print('Response body: ${response.body}');
    
                          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                            final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
                            final bool success = jsonResponse['etat'];
                            final String message = jsonResponse['message'];
    
                            if (success) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                const SnackBar(content: Text("Connexion réussie")),
                              );
                              // Effectuez d'autres actions, par exemple, naviguez vers une autre page
                            } else {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                SnackBar(content: Text(message)),
                              );
                            }
                          } else {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(content: Text("Une erreur s'est produite")),
                            );
                          }
                          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                          print("Connexion de $mail avec le mdp $password");
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text("Se connecter"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SignInPage()),
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        "Vous n'avez pas de compte ? S'inscrire ici",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

}
}
```

Originally I had put this url to access the API: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ but it didn't work, I was getting access errors and when I put my ip there were no more errors (it's not my real ip in the code here).

The print of my response :

```
I/flutter (20958): Response status code: 500
I/flutter (20958): Response body: <!-- Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null (500 Internal Server Error) -->
I/flutter (20958): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter (20958): <html lang="en">
I/flutter (20958):     <head>
I/flutter (20958):         <meta charset="UTF-8" />
I/flutter (20958):         <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
I/flutter (20958):         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
I/flutter (20958):         <title>Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null (500 Internal Server Error)</title>
I/flutter (20958):         <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="data:image/png;base64,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
```

The Error in my Symfony terminal:

> [Web Server ] Jun 28 15:13:39 |ERROR  | SERVER POST (500) /login host="127.0.0.1:8004" ip="192.168.128.1" scheme="https"

This is a first for me with Flutter, I hope that someone will be able to help me if you need more information, please don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, I just forgot my header on the Flutter side so I added this:

```
static const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
```

And like this :

```
final url = Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/login");
var body = jsonEncode({"mail": mail, "password": password});
final response = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: headers,
  body: body,
);
```